# Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG when running via SSH

Tags: java, bash, ssh, command-line

I have a project that I run using the following command:`java -cp ".\target\classes;lib\*;" org.testng.TestNG ParallelTestXML.xml`  and it runs just as it should. I uploaded this project via SSH and want to run it on the remote computer (an AWS ec2 instance), but I get `Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG`. It fails even though I am using the same exact command in the same `Project` folder.

What could be causing this when all dependencies are included within the `Project` folder inside the `lib` folder so how can it not find `testNG`. I can run the project locally no problem.

I even get the same error when I try to run just the Java classes, ignoring the testNG part like this `java -cp "./target/classes/;lib/*" RealPackage.Controller` and I get this error: `Error: Could not find or load main class RealPackage.Controller`.

In both of these cases, I tested them locally and worked fine. The project I uploaded via SSH is this entire project; it should be identical so these is really confusing me that these commands don't work.

You can see that both project locations have the same structure. The Left is my local PC, the right is what is on the AWS server:
[image: Filezilla Image]

EDIT: So after some time I realized its because I was trying to use Windows sytnax on a Linux machine. So now I have come up with this for the Linux amchine: `java -cp .:/target/classes/:lib/* org.testng.TestNG ParallelTestXML.xml`  and it now can't find the classes that are located in the `/target/classes` location.

Comment: "I uploaded this project via SSH" did you upload .java (sources) files or .class (compiled) files (or both)? anyway, check if .class files are there on your server

Comment: Yes they are. Source files and compiled files are Both there

Comment: are you running the command from the "root" of the project? if you run `ls` do you see `target/` folder (and `lib/`)?

Comment: Since your classpath consists of two *relative* paths, it entirely depends on what the *current directory* is when you run the command. Guess it's not what you think it is when you "run it on the remote computer". Perhaps specifying absolute paths would fix the problem.

Comment: yes I looked at it in FileZilla and it looks identical

Comment: I even used a VNC to look at it and its all there. Why else might this be happening?

Comment: Is your EC2 pseudomachine running Windows, Linux, or something else (and what)? VNC suggests Linux, and the command syntax you posted is wrong for Linux, although it would be correct for Windows.

Comment: You are right. I just noticed that myself and my local PC is Windows and the ec2 is Linux. So now I have come up with this `java -cp .:/target/classes/:lib/* org.testng.TestNG ParallelTestXML.xml` but still nothing :/ now it says Cannot find class in classpath: RealPackage.ParallelTests but thats one step closer than before. now it is at least finding testNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the order in which you list the classpath matters. So I just had to rearrange it and it worked.